# Wordpress SEO Plugin issue

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Wordpress SEO Plugin on a WordPress theme that I'm working on but after installation and settings, it still doesn't generate the meta tags. Any idea what the problem could be.  my header code looks as shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes() ?>>


<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>



<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />



<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/s3Slider.js"></script>



<script  type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.js" ></script>

<script  type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextarea.js"></script>

<script  type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/SpryAssets/SpryValidationConfirm.js"></script>







<script type="text/javascript">



    $(document).ready(function() {



        $('#slider').s3Slider({



            timeOut: 8000



        });



    });



</script>





<script type="text/javascript">



   $("#navbar li a").find("a[href='"+window.location.href+"']").each(function(){

$(this).addClass("current")



</script>







</head>















<div id="rack">







   <div id="header">







    <div id="lonum">



    <div id="logo"><a href="http://www.southjerseydentures.com"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/Logo.png" height="176" alt="South Jersey Dentures" border="0"></a></div><!-- End Logo -->



    <div id="number"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/number.png" alt="South Jersey Dentures Phone Number" border="0"></div><!-- End Number -->









    </div><!-- End Lonum -->







     <div id="navbar">



    <?php wp_nav_menu (array('menu'=>'custom_menu'



    ,'menu_class' => 'nav'));?>











     </div><!-- End NavBar -->







   </div><!-- End Header -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in the `<head>...</head>`